# How to UNION 2 CTE results in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

--UNION gives me error

```
;WITH TopSelling 
AS
(
SELECT p.Name AS ProductName,SUM(LineTotal) AS TotalAmount
FROM Product AS p INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail AS sod
ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
GROUP BY p.Name
)


SELECT ProductName, TotalAmount
FROM TopSelling
ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY


UNION ALL

SELECT 'Grand Total' AS ProductName, sum(TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount
FROM TopSelling
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Yeah it was below the fold when I started typing was just about to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ;WITH TopSelling 
    AS
    (
         SELECT p.Name AS ProductName,SUM(LineTotal) AS TotalAmount
         FROM Product AS p INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail AS sod
         ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
         GROUP BY p.Name
    ),
    topSelling1 as 
    (
         SELECT ProductName, TotalAmount
         FROM TopSelling
         ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC
         OFFSET 0 ROWS
         FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
    ),
    total as
    (
         SELECT sum(TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount
         FROM TopSelling;
    )
    select ProductName, TotalAmount
    FROM TopSelling1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Grand Total' AS ProductName, TotalAmount
    FROM Total;
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me please how to make the select with ALL OTHERS? I mean Grand Total - top 5 rows?

Answer (score 1):

So don't use it.  Use `GROUPING SETS` instead:

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.Name, 'Grand Total') AS ProductName,  -- The lazy way
       SUM(LineTotal) AS TotalAmount
FROM Product p INNER JOIN
     SalesOrderDetail sod
     ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (p.Name), () )
ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see, you want the first five rows *and then* the overall total.

Use a subquery:

```
WITH TopSelling AS
     (SELECT p.Name as ProductName, SUM(LineTotal) as TotalAmount
      FROM Product p INNER JOIN
          SalesOrderDetail sod
          ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
      GROUP BY p.Name
    )
SELECT ProductName, TotalAmount
FROM ((SELECT TOP 5 ProductName, TotalAmount, 1 as Priority
       FROM TopSelling
       ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'Grand Total' AS ProductName, sum(TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount, 2 as Priority
       FROM TopSelling
      )
     ) t
ORDER BY Priority, TotalAmount DESC;
```

I find `TOP 5` more natural in this case than `OFFSET`/`FETCH`.  The latter, of course, is more sensible for paging.

Answer (score 0):

remove the alias form the second  select

```
;WITH TopSelling 
AS
(
SELECT p.Name AS ProductName,SUM(LineTotal) AS TotalAmount
FROM Product AS p INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail AS sod
ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
GROUP BY p.Name
)

  SELECT ProductName, TotalAmount
  FROM TopSelling
  ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC
  OFFSET 0 ROWS
  FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'Grand Total' , sum(TotalAmount)
  FROM TopSelling
```

Comment: with `TopSelling`  from the `CTE`?

Comment: I will have to double check, but I dont think the alias have any issue there

Comment: You guys are amazing! Thank you for help!